# Unwittingly not declaring an overload. what do you think?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a function:

```
ViewModel GetviewModel(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Whatever = "something";
    return viewModel
}
```

I called it like this unwittingly in my controller and it didn't complain that I didn't pass the returning model into a variable (because obviously it works off of the reference).

```
GetviewModel(viewModel);
return viewModel;
```

Is there a way to help other developers out by declaring that "yes you can indeed use the GetviewModel function as void type".. something like:

```
ViewModel, void GetviewModel(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Whatever = "something";
    return viewModel
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work :)

I don't want to have to declare a whole overload function with the same content again.

Comment: Are you talking about *overriding* or about *overloading*?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you are asking for. Any return value from a method can be thrown away, it is always up to the caller to use the return value, if they want to. So, what would the additional `, void` express or change?

Comment: SORRRY, updated the question lmao... override = overload, sorry doiiii

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I think your answer is fine, I was wondering if there was a way to state that yes I do plan on people using my function as void aswell... It really isn't a big deal... just hunting for information. Thanks for your response!

Comment: What would maybe help for clarification is showing the code that you want to avoid. i.e. please show the various overloads you would try to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not allow overloading methods with just a changed return-value. Just imagine what it would do to the `var` keyword. What you should do is communicate clearly to other users of your code what it does. Calling a method `GetSomething` that takes a parameter of `Something` and actually just sets a value should ofcourse be called something else. You example should probably be called `UpdateWhatever`.

To summarize: No, you cannot create method overloads on return values only.

Comment: Comment it is then. Thanks matey!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call your function 'UpdateViewModel' and change the return to void, that way others can tell it is modifying state and it doesn't need the return value.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure he sometimes wants to use the return value.

Comment: Your right of course. But his question seems to be about creating additional overload expressions meaning he wants to keep the existing one and add a void one also, which is pointless in itself.

@Jimmyt1988 I think your answer is fine, I was wondering if there was a way to state that yes I do plan on people using my function as void aswell... It really isn't a big deal... just hunting for information. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what your question is. It sounds like your asking how to let other people know your method doesn't need to assign a value to a variable. That's a given. Any return value can either be used or not used.

Your second question seems to be how to let people know that your method does something byRef as oppopsed to byVal. This is also told in the method creation.

Im not sure if I understand what your asking though.